# Problem connecting to AlwaysOn Cluster

Tags: sql-server

Good day, I created a AlwaysOn HA cluster in Azure, 2 Server 2012s both with SQL 2012  Ent updated and patched on the same subnet.. These are the guides I followed:

[Tutorial: AlwaysOn Availability Groups in Windows Azure (GUI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn249504.aspx)
 [Tutorial: Listener Configuration for AlwaysOn Availability Groups in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376546.aspx)

AZURESQL01 and AZURESQL02 are the nodes and with their powers combined they form CAPTAIN_CLUSTER01. There are 3 instances with 3 AG groups and 3 listeners and I opened the firewall ports.

We have a VPN to our AZURE and I can connect to AZURESQL01 and AZURESQL02 and all the instances over the VPN, but I cannot connect to the cluster or the listeners at all. I can do so from either AZURESQL01 or AZURESQL02, but not from outside or our AZURE network. All I get is  various Login timeout messages.

I have double checked the setup and the ports and the DNS entries, but I cannot connect.

Am I a moron and missing something really silly, or is there some configuration not covered in the installation tutorial that I am missing?

Comment: A resolution for this can be found by making sure you use your Public Virtual IP properly and not your network IP as Azure completely ignores any IPs other than the VIP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Azure completely ignores IPs of any internal network on Azure, if you want any computers to connect to a listener in an AlwaysOn availability group make sure 100% sure you specify the VIP, Virtual IP, of the Cloud Service and not the internal IP of the cluster. You will not be able to connect to the cluster or to the listener.

When on the Dashboard view, note the address shown under Public Virtual IP (VIP) Address.
Completely ignore the internal IP Address for listener configuration.